# Text selection in Unix using sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep, rspec

I want to select a particular part of a text file and print it / store in another file.

Selection starts when a particular pattern matches and ends when another pattern matches. And I have to do it without awk.  I'm trying using sed.

- start selection when found ***expected***
- up to when found ***actual***

```
> |e|build_event_details_json(e) })
       expected collection contained:  [{"id"=>18646, "state"=>"available", "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",actual collection contained:    [{"id"=>18646
```

answer should be

```
>  expected collection contained:  [{"id"=>18646, "state"=>"available", "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
```

Comment: (1) Are the `>` characters really part of your data?  (2) Will “***expected***” and “***actual***” always be on the same line?  (3) What have you tried? (Try searching this site.  We get lots of questions like this.)

Comment: `>` this is part of data.  and many regex can also be there. no, **expected** and **actual** can be in different lines and in between them also can be many lines.

Comment: Can you use grep ?

Comment: You mention you "have to do it without `awk`", and as a result try `sed`.  Are other tools permitted?

Comment: `grep` or `sed` can be used... i used this `sed -n '/Started.*'$1'/,/Started.*'$2'/p' filename`. is it usable ?

Comment: (1) I don’t understand why ``>`` appears in your desired output.  You say you want only the text starting with the word ***expected*** up to the word ***actual***, but the `>` is before the word ***expected*** (on a separate line, in fact) in the input.  (2) Can you clarify how you want multi-line input to be handled?  You say you want to get only the text starting with the word ***expected*** up to the word ***actual***, but you have accepted Isaac’s answer, which gives you the lines that appear before ***expected*** and after ***actual**.* … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) Can there be multiple ***expected*** … ***actual*** pairs in the file? (4) Also, what do you want to happen when a line *begins* with ***actual**?* (5) Actually, Isaac’s post contains four different answers.  It would be nice if you indicated which one solves your problem.  Note that his first answer seems to be explicitly wrong, as it prints the text after `actual` on the same line (e.g., `collection contained`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only sed:

```
<infile sed 's/expected/\n&/;s/.*\n//;s/actual/\n&/;s/\nactual.*//'
```

Explanation:

- `s/expected/\n&/` Place a newline (divide) before `expected`.
- `s/.*\n//` Remove the leading line that the previous command created.
- `s/actual/\n&/` Place a newline (divide) before `actual`.
- `s/\nactual.*//` Remove the line created above starting with `actual`.

Note that above will generate an empty line if `actual` is at the start of a line. If that empty line needs to be avoided, use:

```
<infile sed 's/expected/\n&/;s/.*\n//;/^actual/d;s/actual.*//'
```

Also note that the above command(s) will keep unmodified all lines that don't match either `expected` or `actual` and then will be printed.
To avoid this prepend `/expected\|actual/!d` as this:

```
<infile sed '/expected\|actual/!d;s/expected/\n&/;s/.*\n//;/^actual/d;s/actual.*//'
```

If what is required is the **range** of lines between `expected` and `actual`, but removing the trailing line containing `actual` then use:

```
<infile sed '/^expected/!{s/expected/\n&/};/^actual/!{s/actual.*/\n&/}' |  
        sed '/expected/,/actual/!d;/actual/d'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not too elegant, nor efficient, but does the job

```
sed 's/actual/\n&/' file | sed -n '/expected/,/actual/p' | sed '$d'
       expected collection contained:  [{"id"=>18646, "state"=>"available", "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
```

Mayhap a wee bit better (with GNU `sed`):

```
sed -n '/expected/,$ {s/actual.*$//; p; T; q; } ' file
```

Should the `T` command be unavailable, try

```
sed -n '/expected/,$ {s/actual.*$//; p; tL; b; :L; q; } ' file
```

Comment: This solution prints only the first instance of the range, not others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
 sed -n '/expected.*actual/{s/actual.*//;p;n};
         /expected/,/actual/{s/actual.*//;p}' input
```

If a line contains both start and end marker, discard everything after the end marker and read the next line. Otherwise, print anything between the lines containing the start and end marker, again discarding everything after the end marker.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're trying to parse JSON with sed. Not a good idea. Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) if possible.

Nevertheless, you can slurp the whole file into memory, and to a search and replace on it:

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
> |e|build_event_details_json(e) })
       expected collection contained:  [
       {"id"=>18646,
       "state"=>"available",
       "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
       actual collection contained:    [
       {"id"=>18646
baz
qux

$ sed -n 'H;${g;s/.*\(expected.*\)actual.*/\1/p}' file
expected collection contained:  [
       {"id"=>18646,
       "state"=>"available",
       "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
```

Note that this will output from the **last** 'expect' to the **last** following 'actual'
due to the greediness of the `*` quantifier

```
$ cat file
foo
expect1
bar
> |e|build_event_details_json(e) })
       expected collection contained:  [
       {"id"=>18646,
       "state"=>"available",
       "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
       actual collection contained:    [
       {"id"=>18646
baz
actual2
qux

$ sed -n 'H;${g;s/.*\(expected.*\)actual.*/\1/p}' file
expected collection contained:  [
       {"id"=>18646,
       "state"=>"available",
       "salesEndAtUtc"=>"2018-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
       actual collection contained:    [
       {"id"=>18646
baz
```